# Updating a Sharepoint list with input from an Excel file using Power Automate

Tags: list, excel, power-automate

I previously did this using MS Access.
I have a worksheet in an Excel file, let's call it the input, that is the source for the update for a Sharepoint list.
For easier labelling, I'll call the item that is on this Excel file sheet a row.
If the row is already on the Sharepoint list (I compare the ID number), it will update a certain field of that item.
If the row is not yet on the Sharepoint list (ID number is zero), it will add the row to the Sharepoint list.
Is that possible using Power Automate?